# iphone is this error about linking?

Tags: iphone, object, file, hyperlink

Im importing some files to make a [calendar](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244) in my app, but I get the following error,

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CheckmarkTile", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-CheckmarkTile in RosterCrViewController.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KLCalendarView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-KLCalendarView in RosterCrViewController.o

 ld: symbol(s) not found
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

wich looks exactly like this post solution 
[Linking Error: Symbol Not Found](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/linking-error-symbol-not-found.html)

[image]

but the problem (basic, noob here!, ;p )

is I dont know how to bring this screen to show the "files that make up the final executable" (to check that and hopefully fix the error)

[image: link files executable]

[EDIT] OK thanks to Rajender, now I have my files checked, but now I get 8 errors!, why o why (all files are ticked now)
[image]

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CheckmarkTile"  this type of errors come when the class 'CheckmarkTile' is not the member of current target.

you have to make the member of current target.

there are two ways to remove these errors:-

1. right click on Groups & Files in the xCode and select Target Membership. Now make sure that the membership check box is on for the class CheckmarkTile.

2. just drag the file named CheckmarkTile to the active Target->Compile Sources.

Thats all what you need to solve these errors.
```

Comment: hi, thank you, for your answer, but now I get a complete new set of errors! haha, what could it be? as I now tick all the necessary files? please see the edited question with the image of the error, thank you

Comment: Hi, I think QuartzCore framework is missing form your project.So please add QuartzCore framework in your project and compile it again. This will fix all the errors